# Powershell: Convert certificates to pfx with a loop

Tags: powershell, loops, certificate, pfx

I'm trying to convert a bunch of certificates to pfx format with a loop as there are many. The issue I'm running into is in regards to the private key. I am unsure of how to loop the right private key with the right cert. Below is my loop

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath\SCP -Recurse -Include "*cer", "*.key" | 
ForEach-Object {
    $OutFile = $_.FullName.ToString().Replace(".cer",".pfx")
    $Password = Read-host "enter the password" -AsSecureString
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in $CertPath\Folder -inkey $PrivateKey -out $Outfile -password $Password}
```

Comment: If the `basename` of the key and cert file matches, just do another replace —> `$key = $_.fullname.tostring().replace('.cer','.key')`

Comment: @AdminOfThings. That seems to have done the trick! If you wouldn't mind posting this as an answer so I can give credit

Comment: Thanks. I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Basename` of the key and cert file matches, just do another replace:

```
$key = $_.FullName.ToString().Replace('.cer','.key')
```